# "0" との比較

Tags: java

条件式はresult[i]の値が0の場合は9としたいのですが、実行したら"20092812345"の0のところが"//"と置き換わってしまいました。
これはif文の式がいけないのでしょうか？
どうしてか教えていただきたいです。

**ソースコード**

```
class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        angouka test01 = new angouka();
        System.out.println(test01.net("20092812345"));


}

public String net(String in) {
    char[] result = in.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

        if(result[i] == 0) {
            result[i] = 9;
        }else {
            --result[i];
        }
    }

    return new String(result);
}
```

**実行結果**

```
1//81701234
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

うまくプログラムが作れないのは、文字(char)と整数(int)の区別がちゃんとついていない事にあると思われます。

質問のプログラムが実行されていく過程を追って、確認していきましょう。

mainクラスのmainメソッドで、angoukaクラスの変数 test01の netメソッドが"20092812345"という文字列を引数として呼び出されます。

```
    angouka test01 = new angouka();
    System.out.println(test01.net("20092812345"));
```

netメソッドでは、変数resultに、"20092812345"を toCharArrayメソッドで文字の配列にしたものが入ります。
　result の値は、["2","0","0","9","2","8","1","2","3","4","5"]となる訳です。

問題は、for文の中にあります。

```
    if(result[i] == 0) {
        result[i] = 9;
    }else {
        --result[i];
    }
```

if文の条件は、「result[i] == 0」となっていますが、result[i]は文字(char)、0は整数(int)ですから、等しくなる事はあり得ません。
そのため、ループのたびに「--result[i];」が実行されます。

charは、文字を表すコードで表現されます。"0"は、0x30(16進数で30という意味で、ビットで表現すると、00110000)、"9"は、0x3A(ビットで表現すると、00111001)です。
この文字コードの体系は、"American Standard Code for Information Interchange"（ASCII)と呼ばれます。ASCIIで表現できる文字は、数字、記号、アルファベットです。ASCIIコードの表へのリンクを下に置きますから、リンクをクリックしてASCIIコード表を見てみてください。

[ASCIIコード表](https://www.k-cube.co.jp/wakaba/server/ascii_code.html)

"0"は、0x30で表されると書きました。
もし、i=1で、result[i]が"0"の時に、「--result[i];」が実行されると、どうなると思いますか？

"0"(ビット表現で00110000)から1が引かれて、0x00101111(16進数で2F)になります。
0x2Fは"/"という文字の文字コードです。

これが「0のところが"//"と置き換わってしまいました」という現象が起きた理由です。

具体的には、["2","0","0","9","2","8","1","2","3","4","5"]であったresultの値が、「--result[i];」がループで順に適用されることによって、["1","/","/","8","1","7","0","1","2","3","4"]になった。
これをprintすれば、「1//81701234」となりますよね。

Comment: "9"の文字コードは、0x3Aではなく0x39でした。訂正します。

Comment: ありがとうございます。すいません、わからないのですが、
"0"(ビット表現で00110000)から1が引かれて、0x00101111(16進数で2F)になります。
→char型の”０”からint型の１をひくと0x00101111(16進数で2F)ということでしょうか？

Comment: ２進数表現の 00110000 (10進数の24)から、1引くと10進数の23(２進数表現の00101111)になります。
そしてASCIIコードでは、00101111は、"/"という文字に対応するコードなんです。

http://ja0qon.my.coocan.jp/labo/pic_start/data/dec_hex_bin_conv.pdf に１０進数、１６進数、２進数の対応表がありますから参考にしてください。

Answer (score 3):

文字コードと文字が表している整数値との区別がついていないようです。

この行

```
char[] result = in.toCharArray();
```

を実行した後、`result`は、`char`型の配列となり、`{'2', '0', '0', '1', ...}`となるのですが、`char`型の`'2'`と言う値は整数値の`50`、`'0'`と言う値は整数値の`48`を表します。これはJavaが採用しているUnicodeのコード値(UTF-16のコードポイント)になります。

文字コードの`0`は、NUL文字を表しており、普通の文字列中には現れませんから、`result[i] == 0`という条件は成立せず、常に`else`の側が実行されることになります。

(`'0' == 48`であり、`'0' == 0`は成立しません。)

元の文字が`'0'`の場合、その文字コードは`48`、そこから1を引いた`47`が`result[i]`に入るのですが、それは文字コードとしてはスラッシュ(`'/'`)を表しているので、`'0'`は`'/'`に変換されているのです。

文字として`result[i]`の内容を比較したり、設定したりするのであれば、文字定数リテラル`'~'`を使用しましょう。

```
    public String net(String in) {
        char[] result = in.toCharArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            if(result[i] == '0') {
                result[i] = '9';
            }else {
                --result[i];
            }
        }

        return new String(result);
    }
```

出力:

```
19981701234
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！
'0'と言う値は整数値の48を表します。→今実行したら９が表示されたのですが、

Comment: @iuy さん、「今実行したら９が表示された」の部分が何をされたのかがよくわかりません。どのコードを実行して、どの部分に9が表示されたのかはっきりさせてもらえると、何か補足できることがあるかもしれません。